# Determine whether the function $g(x,y) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(x-2y)^k \sin(kx + y)}{\sqrt{k!} (1 + x^{2k}y^{4k})}$is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-convergence

> Determine whether the function $$g(x,y) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(x-2y)^k \sin(kx + y)}{\sqrt{k!} (1 + x^{2k}y^{4k})}$$is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

**My attempt:** I tried to use Weierstrass M-test, to prove that $g$ is the uniform convergence of continuous partial sums. However, for each $k \geq 1$, I only obtained the following bound for each $(x,y) \in\mathbb{R}^2$,
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{(x-2y)^k \sin(kx + y)}{\sqrt{k!} (1 + x^{2k}y^{4k})} \right| &\leq \frac{(|x| + 2 |y|)^k}{\sqrt{k!}} \leq \frac{2^{k-1} |x|^k}{\sqrt{k!}} + \frac{2^{2k-1} |y|^k}{\sqrt{k!}}\\
&\leq \frac{1}{2} \frac{|2x|^k}{\sqrt{k!}} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{|4y|^k}{\sqrt{k!}}
\end{align*}
However, I am unable to find a bound $M_k$ for the above expression $\frac{(x-2y)^k \sin(kx + y)}{\sqrt{k!} (1 + x^{2k}y^{4k})}$ independent of $x$ and independent of $y$ for each $k$ so that the series $\sum M_k < \infty.$

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: If you're only interested in continuity, then uniform convergence on compact sets is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

To prove the continuity of $g$, it is enough to verify that the series converges uniformly on each compact. For this, you can use Weierstrass M-test and pick up the norm $\lVert (x,y) \rVert_1 = \lvert x \rvert + \lvert y \rvert$ (all norms are equivalent on $\mathbb R^2$). Then you have

$$\left\lvert \frac{(x-2y)^k \sin(kx + y)}{\sqrt{k!} (1 + x^{2k}y^{4k})} \right\rvert \le \frac{2^k A^k}{\sqrt{k!}}$$ for $\lVert (x,y) \rVert_1 \le A$. I let you continue from there.

Comment: Thank you. Do you might sharing why should uniform convergence in compact subsets be sufficient for continuity? and for what properties of functions need not hold when there is only uniform convergence in compact subsets but not on the entire metric space.

Comment: @L-JS Continuity is a local property. If you have uniform convergence on compact sets, you get continuity of the limit on each compact set, and thus at each point of the domain since you consider all posssible compact sets. Moreover, since you only need to have continuity at each point, it suffices to check uniform convergence on a well-chosen collection of compact sets that cover all of the domain of the function.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification.